# Does Rek'sai's Tremor Sense "see" any champions that fly or float?

Tags: league-of-legends

Can Rek'Sai's Tremor Sense sense champions that continually fly or float?

To me it would seem silly as she is sensing vibrations.

Comment: I edited your question to remove the part that was making this question encroach on developer intent. Developer intent questions are off topic here.

Comment: @Dragonrage You shouldn't have edited that out, as the answer has been actually given by the game developers on several ocasions

Comment: @Oak it's about developer intent, therefore off topic.

Comment: @Dragonrage "**Speculative** questions about developer intent, with respect to both mechanics and narrative". If it's stated by the developers, it's not speculation, it's information, and as such on topic

Comment: @Oak the problem is, what if we don't have a dev statement? What if they've just not said it *yet* or we can't *find* it? How do you even go about proving that? In general, topicness of questions that need certain answer types as proof is a game we don't want to really get into. You should be able to judge topicality without an answer ever being posted, which is why we have the rule we do.

Comment: Why is it silly to sense flying/floating objects by vibrations? Air molecules vibrate too, you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Rek'Sai can sense flying/jumping units. This happens because while in our world we have 3 dimensions, the game only has 2.

A flying unit, or a jumping unit doesn't "jump / fly". They simply "walk" as usual. You just see it as flight or a jump because of how the game visuals are designed.

This is also valid for traps. If, for example, Tristana tries to jump over Jinx's chompers, she will still get rooted.

Comment: Oh wow didn't know about the tristana jumping on chompers!

Comment: "It works because the game only has two dimensions" is a *terrible* answer.  It does nothing to explain the mechanics, except to say, "It does because the game says it does"

Comment: But it is the reason why it happens. The game recognizes 2 axis. Any and all jumps are considered dashes as per the game's code, which, in other words means : they "don't jump". They don't jump, because they don't have a zed axis

Comment: Just pointing out that flying or jumping is a visual effect, but has no difference on movement, would be fine.  The top section isn't needed at all, and is what drops the quality of this answer.

Comment: So the technical explanation of why the game doesn't consider a jump as a jump is a bad thing?

Comment: I wouldn't call that a technical explanation at all.  It's not even an explanation.  It's a circular reason; "it works that way because the game works that way."  You might as well have said, "Because the game says it does."  Does that help?  Does that explain anything?  Nope.

Comment: Dimensions of movement is relatively meaningless, mechanically, when a character in flight or otherwise in a state where they would not be touching the ground could, conceivably, have a boolean value attached to a variable like "IsTouchingGround". It's not like there haven't been games on a 2d plane that haven't been able to differentiate between 'flying' and 'not flying' objects before

Comment: I think the technical explanation is indeed helpful, however, it could defiantly be worded better. That said, unless they made drastic changes since the early days, I disagree completely that the game only perceives 2 dimensions. If there was no understanding of the third axis, trees would be a static collision, and you would not be able to jump over them with abilities such as Corkis jump.

Comment: The game does only understand 2 dimensions, though yes there are 3 dimensions we can visually see on the screen. Collision occurs when  a champion tries to occupy the same space as terrain. Fail flashes for example, fail because if it were to put you were you cast flash, you would end up inside/on the wall which is not allowed, that's collision. Casting abilities, like Corki's valkyrie as @Timelord64 mentions, only detects collision at the end of the cast, not while moving through terrain. Example for an ability that isn't allowed to cross terrain would be Vayne's tumble.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill, I notice collision at all stages of valkyrie. Trees of certain height can not be crossed, and at about medium level, corki is pushed around them - even in the middle of flight.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill vayne tumble can cross some terrain.

Comment: Other examples are shens dash, ahris R, caitlyns net, etc. I know from experience that despite the 'end point' of the dash being inside the dragon pit, there are certain areas that are not passable due to higher ground. This applies at various points throughout the map. Timelord is correct in what he says, at least in my experience

Comment: None of those examples require the height dimension to be considered to be explained. Every dash skill can be specifically changed to cross certain terrain or not. Example: The Hecarim E dash used to be incapable of crossing terrain, until it, and it alone, has been changed to be able to cross certain terrain under certain circumstances.

Comment: Whether or not you like the answer this is the answer. There is no specific reason why they choose not to distinguish between flying and not, they just don't for anything.

Answer (score 2):

Sure lore-wise Rek'sai probably detects ground-based vibrations, but in-game there is no practical way to differentiate when a champion is either on the ground or in the air. For Tremor Sense the game only detects location, not ground based enemies.

It would also be a huge balance issue to negate Rek'sai's Tremor Sense just by picking a champion that floats such as Malzahar or Nami. Champions aren't allowed to simply ignore rules and should all be affected by abilities the same way.

Rek'sai's Tremor Sense isn't a constant detection either and most dashes/jumps are quick and last maybe a second if not less. This means even if you weren't detectable while in the air, it would be for such a short time that it would make a difference anyways.

Comment: Detecting if a champion is in the air or not would be a very simple check. You literally only need a Boolean value to store it.

Comment: @Dragonrage It would be, but the game does not and probably will not. VanBuzzKill is absolutely correct in that the game does not consider height values for gameplay reasons. Everything counts as on the ground at all times, regardless of abilities used or CC effects suffered (e.g. knockup). Introducing such an "airborne" variable for general gameplay would bring its own problems with it. For example, should a Blitzcrank hook still hit a target that is airborne, or not? Should Rammus ult affect airborne targets, or not? The game would be very different with that "simple" change.

Comment: Actually the game clearly can tell when someone is in the air, Yasuo's ult only works on airbourne targets and originally on the PBE he could ult something like Tristana's jump. There are still a couple abilities he can ult on like Nami's Q which are not knockups. It is tracked, it is just ignored for everything except Yasuo's ult.

Comment: @Probst that's not the result of any height information, but the result of specifically coded interactions. Yasuo can ult off any kind of displacement CC, such as Thresh hook or Janna ult, where the target is clearly not shown as airborne.

Comment: I never said it was because of height information, it is a boolean for airbourn just like Dragonrage said. You are incorrect when you say that the game does not track that, it does it just doesn't use it for anything other than as a more general form of CC than knockback. As for ulting off of any displacement CC yes of course you can, those are also airborne effects. The champion would have to be thrown off the ground to move them wouldn't they? Imo it doesn't make much sense to work on Thresh's Q since that's more dragging them along the ground but someone at Riot decided it counts so it does

Comment: The question is asking about champions that fly or float to get around like Anivia Malzahar and Nami. Should they get an advantage against Rek'sai just because they don't touch the ground? What about Kha'zix, when you evolve his wings he occasionally goes "airborne" just in his walk animation. Should we detect those frames and make him undetectable to Rek'sai then? You can see this would become impractical very quickly. Even Taric and (Dragon Trainer) Tristana float around when they move fast enough such as with homeguards or ally speed buffs.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill, your mainframe points regarding the question. However, we are pointing out flaws in how you explain the answer, so the question is really irrelevant.

Comment: "No practical way to tell if champion is on ground or in air".. I count at least three testaments to separate cases where it already does.

Comment: This is a simple question that everyone is heavily overcomplicating. Can rek'sai detect enemies in flight? No, no she can't. Why do we need to explain how the game works to answer this?